# what jquery library is used for the input text keyword buttons here in Tags below?

Tags: jquery

I don't know how better to describe it, but I'm trying to figure out what library is being used to make the Tags input beneath to generate those single keyword buttons with a click listener that deletes the button when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the same but [this plugin](http://levycarneiro.com/projects/tag-it/example.html) has very similar functionality. The source is [here](http://levycarneiro.com/projects/tag-it/js/)

FYI, the term for this type of control is 'autocomplete tags'.

Comment: cool, thanks! Will leave this open for a while longer to see if anyone knows if there is jQuery solution.

Comment: upon closer inspection, this is nice, but I really need the values! There's no documentation.  The two things that I really want are the values of tags as well as a way to hook into the clickClose event, so that I can do other updates when the tag is removed.